# How to internalize PropertyMap in graph-tool

Tags: python, graph-tool

I'm using python package graph-tool, and facing an error trying to internalize boolean PropertyMap, the way described at http://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/quickstart.html#graph-views. Here is an example code:

```
from graph_tool.all import *

g = price_network(500)
filtered = g.new_vertex_property("bool")
for v in g.vertices(): 
    filtered[v] = True

g.properties["filtered"] = filtered
```

The last line produces a

```
TypeError: value for 't' must be one of: v, e, g
```

Anyone knows how to put it right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it is described in the [documentation](http://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/quickstart.html#internal-property-maps), you should use the `vertex_properties` attribute:

```
g.vertex_properties["filtered"] = filtered
```

or equivalently:

```
g.vp["filtered"] = filtered
```

If you want to use the `properties` attribute directly, you have to pass the key type as well:

```
g.properties[('v', "filtered")] = filtered
```

This is because different types of property maps (e.g. vertex or edge) can have the same name. This is all covered [here](http://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/graph_tool.html#graph_tool.Graph.properties).